# gcc -O2 is smaller then gcc -O2 -g followed by strip --strip-all

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, strip

I am building code that I want to produce release versions. However I also want to be able to debug `cores` if they crash.

So I read that building with debug symbols can be used followed by producing a copy of the binary that you run strip on. Then you can take the core produced by the stripped binary (the released/customer binary) and then gdb this against your copy of the binary with debug symbols...

So step one for me was to generate the binary, I do:

- `gcc -O2 ... -o testbin_release_orig` (original release bin without symbols)
- `gcc -O2 -g ... -o testbin_debug` (full debug binary)
- `cp testbin_debug testbin_release`
- `strip --strip-all testbin_release` (stripped debug binary)

This produces three files with different sizes:

- testbin_release_orig: ~1.7Mb
- testbin_debug: ~13Mb
- testbin_release: ~2.1Mb

My question is, why is `testbin_release` not exactly the same size as `testbin_release_orig`? I am guessing that strip can't strip all the debug symbols that gcc adds. But there is about 0.4Mb of "extra stuff" - what does that consist of?

Comment: You could try using `objdump --all-headers` to view the basic section info -- names, sizes etc.

Comment: @G.M. so... they are basically the same up until the symbold table, where the stripped version has no symbol table and the release version does... that makes sense since I used strip-all. But this does not show why the stripped one is larger (infact on-its-own it suggests that the release version is larger since it has a complete symbol table). I might try to do a diff on the whole objdump, but I expect that to be quite messy :o

Comment: I did an `objdumg -g` for debug symbols - the difference in the release and stripped output file size (of the objdump) was ~0.4Mb... so that tells me that 0.4Mb of debug symbols where not stripped... but ... why?

Comment: Try running `strip -S -v testbin_release` to see what strip is modifying, and compare the output of `strip -v testbin_release_orig` to `strip -v testbin_release`, to see what symbols might be lingering. The main thing, I believe, is that debug symbols may well be stripped, but that doesn't mean that the debug binary doesn't contain additional instructions (e.g. `assert`'s or whatever), which aren't stripped.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem hmm.. the `strip -v ...` command just produces a single line of output for both: `copy from 'testbin_release' [elf32-i386] to 'stBQgfVX' [elf32-i386]`, except for the hash number the output is the same... is that what you meant?

Comment: TBH, I can't remember what I was hoping `-v` to tell you :P... I'm afraid I can't tell you where that extra .4Mb went to. My guess: the optimiser isn't performing in the exact same manner because of the debug symbols. Even though, when debugging, the code won't line up 100% because of the optimisation level, it's possible the `-g` flag keeps that to an acceptable minimum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is from the debug code.

For an 1.7 MB executable you are probably using a library or two. Usually they have something like:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    // some debug code
#endif
```

Also common practice for big projects, so some of it may be your code as well.

`strip` removes only the symbols. The debug code stays.

Comment: Ah, I see - that makes a lot of sense : )

Comment: I don't think `-g` flag would introduce `_DEBUG` flag. At least `gcc 12` does not.